# Assigning values to buttons in Tkinter and appending them in a list (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

Beginner here, so sorry in advance for any stupid questions =] I have huge problems making the program i'm working with graphical though. The player gets to choose between 4 options, "study, "exam","sleep" and "party". Depending on what he chooses, I want the choice to be appended to the list that keeps track of all choices. This is no problem if I don't make it graphical, but when I try it graphical I'm just lost. I've tried creating 4 buttons, and then just try to attatch a value to each button (the value would be "sleep","study","exam", etc) and then use the StringVar()-function, but doesn't seem to work for me :) This is what i've been writing so far (it's probably really bad :s):

```
from tkinter import *
list1 = ['sleep','party','sleep']
root = Tk()
root.title("test!")
root.geometry("500x200")
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Application,self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        Label(self,
              text = "Welcome to the game!"
              ).grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.favorite = StringVar()
        self.favorite.set(None)
        self.btn1 = Button(self, text = "study", command =self.update_text, value = "study")
        self.btn1.grid()
        self.btn2 = Button(self, text = "party", command = self.update_text, value = "party")
        self.btn2.grid()
        self.btn3 = Button(self, text = "exam", command = self.update_text, value = "exam")
        self.btn3.grid()
        self.btn4 = Button(self, text = "sleep", command = self.update_text, value = "sleep")
        self.btn4.grid()

    def update_text(self):
        message = "Your choice was "
        message += value
        print(message)
        lista1.append(value)

app = Application(root)
app.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks a lot and sorry if this is really basic

Comment: there is no such thing as stupid questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the value as **argument**. Try this & then tell if you encounter any problem

Comment: tried this!
def create_widgets(self,value=None):
        self.btn1 = Button(self, text = "study", command =self.update_text, self.value = "study")

But I get an error message saying that keyword can't be an expression. Does that mean I can't use value as an argument or am I using it wrong?

Comment: for calling method :`command=lambda:self.update_text('study')` & for method use `def update_text(self,value)`